# Better or Faster: String.Contains vs List.Contains

Tags: performance, conventions

I know this is a stupid question, but I feel like someone might want to know (or inform a <redacted> co-worker about) this. I am not attaching a specific programming language to this since I think it could apply to all of them. Correct me if I am wrong about that.

**Main question**: Is it faster and/or better to look for entries in a constant `String` or in a `List<String>`?

Details: Let's say that I want to see if a given extension is in a list of supported extensions. Which of the following is the best (in regards to programming style) and/or fastest:

```
const String SUPPORTED = ".exe.bin.sh.png.bmp" /*etc*/;

public static bool IsSupported(String ext){
    ext = Normalize(ext);//put the extension in some expected state like lowercase
    //String.Contains
    return SUPPORTED.Contains(ext);
}
```

---

```
final static List<String> SUPPORTED = MakeAnImmutableList(".exe", ".bin", ".sh",
      ".png",".bmp" /*etc*/);
public static bool IsSupported(String ext){
    ext = Normalize(ext);//put the extension in some expected state like lowercase
    //List.Contains
    return SUPPORTED.Contains(ext);
}
```

Comment: Write a test app and benchmark them yourself, in your language of choice, to settle your disagreement with your co-worker. Use representative data for the task you have in mind. There is no generic *one size fits all for all languages and all data* answer.

Comment: This code is obviously meant to do something with a file.  Whatever you do with that file will take many orders of magnitude more time than what Contains() takes.  Back of the envelope, assume a ridiculously fast and predictable disk that can supply the file data in 50 +/- 1 microseconds.  Contains() ought to be around 50 nanoseconds.  So the overall operation takes 50.05 microseconds.  A faster Contains might take half the time, the overall operation takes 50.025 microseconds.  Your effort gave you a 0.05% speedup.  You can't even measure that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it is important to note that the solutions are not functionally equivalent. The substring search will return *true* for strings like `x` and `exe.bin` while the `List<String>.contains()` will not. In that sense the `List<String>` version is likely to be closer to the semantic you want. Any possible performance comparison should keep that in mind.

Now, on to performance.

### Theoretical

From an asymptotic and algorithm complexity point of view, the `List<String>.contains()` approach will be faster than the other alternative as the length of the strings grows. Conceptually, the `String.contains` version needs to look for a match *at each position* in the `SUPPORTED` String, while the `List.contains()` version only needs to match starting at the start of each substring - as soon as finds a mismatch in the current candidate, it skips to the next. This is related to the above note that the options aren't functionally equivalent: the `String.contains` options can in theory match a much wider universe of inputs, so it has to do more work before rejecting candidates.

Complexity-wise, this difference could be something like `O(N)` for `List.contains()` versus `O(N^2)` for `String.contains()` if you take N to be the *number of candidates* and assume each candidate has a bounded length, and to the `String.contains()` method in the usual brute-force "look for a match starting at each position" algorithm.  As it turns out, the Java `String.contains()` implementation isn't exactly doing the basic `O(N^2)` search, but it isn't doing Boyer-Moore either. In general you can expect that once the substrings get long enough, the `List.String` approach will be faster.

### Close(r) to the Metal

At a closer to the metal perspective, both approaches have their advantages. The `String.contains()` solution avoids the overhead of iterating over the `List` elements: the entire call will be spent in the intrinsified `String.contains` implementation, and all the `char`s making up the entire `SUPPORTED` Strings are contiguous, so this is memory-friendly. The `List.contains()` approach will spend a lot of time doing the double-dereferencing needed to go from each `List` element to the contained `String` and then to the contained `char[]` array, and this is likely to dominate if the strings you are comparing against are very short.

On other hand, the `List.contains` solution ultimately calls into `String.equals` which is likely implemented in terms of `Arrays.equal(char[], char[])` which is heavily optimized with SSE and AVX intrinsics on x86 platforms and likely to be blazing fast, even compared to the optimized version of `String.contains()`. So if the Strings become long, again expect `List.contains()` to pull ahead.

All that said, there is a simple, canonical way to do this quickly: a `HashSet<String>` with all the candidate strings. That's just a simple `String.hash()` (which is cached and so often "free") and a single lookup in the hash table.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it can vary from implementation to implementation, but if want to look to this problem in a generalized way, lets see.

If you want to look for a specific sub-string inside a string, let say a file extension inside a immutable string containing different extensions, you just need to traverse the string with extensions once.

In the other hand, with a list of immutable strings, still need to traverse each one of the string in that list **plus** the overhead of iterate over that list.

As a conclusion, in a generalized way, you can see that using a list to store the strings need more processing.

But, you can look to both solutions by its readability, maintainability, etc. For example, if you want to add or remove new extensions or apply more complex operations, may worth the overhead using a list of string.